# Regex to find variants of "Google"

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-challenge, regex

From the HackerRank question definition:

> The word google can be spelled in many different ways.
>
> E.g. google, g00gle, g0oGle, g<>0gl3, googl3, GooGIe etc...
>
> Because
>
> g = G
>
> o = O = 0 = () = [] = <>
>
> l = L = I
>
> e = E = 3
>
> That's the problem here to solve.
>
> And the match has to be only this single word, nothing more, nothing
>   less.
>
> E.g.
>
> "g00gle" = True, "g00gle " = False, "g google" = False, "GGOOGLE" =
>   False, "hey google" = False

**What I'm looking in review**: How can I make my code more pythonic?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re

g = ["g", "G"]
o = ["o", "O", "0", "()", "[]", "<>"]
l = ["l", "L", "I"]
e = ["e", "E", "3"]

regex = (g, o, o, g, l, e)
regex = ((re.escape(y) for y in x) for x in regex)
regex = ("(?:{})".format("|".join(x)) for x in regex)
regex = "^{}$".format("".join(regex))

print(bool(re.match(regex, input())))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Honestly there's not much code to comment on, it's also a programming challenge, so there's not much incentive to make it any better than it is. I too would have done it your way.

The only objective criticism I have is I'd just add a function `regex_options` to build the non-capturing group.

Other than that I'd apply this to the creation of `g`, `o`, `l` and `e`. As I think it's a little cleaner. But you may want to perform it before `"".join`, and after `regex = (g, o, o, g, l, e)`.

```
import re


def regex_options(options):
    options = (re.escape(o) for o in options)
    return "(?:{})".format("|".join(options))


g = regex_options(["g", "G"])
o = regex_options(["o", "O", "0", "()", "[]", "<>"])
l = regex_options(["l", "L", "I"])
e = regex_options(["e", "E", "3"])

regex = "^{}$".format("".join((g, o, o, g, l, e)))

print(bool(re.match(regex, input())))
```

If this were professional code, I'd suggest using an `if __name__ == '__main__':` block, and possibly a `main` function.

Comment: I like this solution better, because it doesn't repeatedly redefine `regex` and change its type.